# Do the Owncloud clients use encryption when transferring files to and from the server?

Tags: encryption

Do the Owncloud clients use encryption when transferring files to and from the server?

I understand that files are stored un-encrypted on the server, but I’m wondering if they are secured during transit to and from the server.

I’ve been looking at their website (http://owncloud.org/), but haven’t been able to find an answer.

I am looking to setup my own server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By design, OwnCloud sits on top of a web server. You can configure SSL on the web server as you would any website or web application.

This [link](http://ubuntuserverguide.com/2013/04/how-to-setup-owncloud-server-5-with-ssl-connection.html) you provide you enough information to get you started.